# ActiveJob instance variables are not stored in DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, background-process, delayed-job, rails-activejob

My question is quite straightforward.

Using custom class I'm able to do this:

```
class Job
  def message=(message)
    @message = message
  end

  def perform
    puts @message
  end
end

job = Job.new
job.message = 'hello'
Delayed::Job.enqueue job
Delayed::Job.last.invoke_job
# hello
# => nil
```

While using `ActiveJob::Base` class I can't:

```
job = MyJob.new

class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  def message= (message)
    @message = message
  end

  def perform(*args)
    puts @message
  end
end

job = MyJob.new
job.message = 'hello'
job.enqueue
Delayed::Job.last.invoke_job

# Performed MyJob (Job ID: a8cadf34-f7f7-406d-abcf-cd96589acdf2) from DelayedJob(default) in 3.58ms
# => nil
```

And the reason is that `JobWrapper`, which doesn't contain custom attributes, is being inserted into table instead of job instance itself:

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("handler", "run_at", "queue", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper
job_data:
  job_class: MyJob
  job_id: a8cadf34-f7f7-406d-abcf-cd96589acdf2
  provider_job_id: 
  queue_name: default
  priority: 
  arguments: []
  executions: 0
  locale: en
', '2018-10-23 16:34:58.363428', 'default', '2018-10-23 16:34:58.363570', '2018-10-23 16:34:58.363570') RETURNING "id"
```

I am aware of `perform_later` syntax and other relative details, please, don't just tell me *"You just use it wrong"*.

Is it an intended behaviour or is it prohibited to do so? If not, is there any workaround?